# Setup what kind of push notification is displayed in ios / cordova / pushbots

Tags: ios, cordova, apple-push-notifications, pushbots

I'm currently sending push notifications to my Phonegap app via the Pushbots plugin. But with the initial settings the message gets displayed as a banner (only on the top and without the open/dismiss buttons). I would like to display it as an alert! Is that possible?

What do I have to do to change that programmatically?

Here is the ObjC code of the pushbots plugin:

```
#import "PushbotsPlugin.h"

@implementation PushbotsPlugin

- (void)initializeWithAppId:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command {
    [self.commandDelegate runInBackground:^{
        CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = nil;

        NSString* appId = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [Pushbots sharedInstanceWithAppId:appId];
        });

        pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK];
        [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
    }];
}

- (void) setAlias:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command
{
    NSLog(@"Executing setAlias(Alias)");

    CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = nil;

    NSString* alias = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];

    [[Pushbots sharedInstance] sendAlias:alias];

    pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK];
    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
}

- (void) debug:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command
{
    NSLog(@"Executing debug(debug)");

    CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = nil;

    BOOL debug = [[command.arguments objectAtIndex:0]  isEqual:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];

    [[Pushbots sharedInstance] debug:debug];

    pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK];
    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
}

- (void) tag:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command
{
    NSLog(@"Executing tag(Tag)");

    CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = nil;

    NSString* tag = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];

    [[Pushbots sharedInstance] tag:tag];

    pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK];
    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
}

- (void) getToken:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command
{
    NSLog(@"Executing getToken()");

    CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = nil;

    NSString* deviceId = [[Pushbots sharedInstance] getDeviceID];
    pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:deviceId];
    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
}

- (void) untag:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command
{
    NSLog(@"Executing untag(Tag)");

    CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = nil;

    NSString* tag = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];

    [[Pushbots sharedInstance] untag:tag];

    pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK];
    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
}

- (void) resetBadge:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command
{
    [self.commandDelegate runInBackground:^{
        CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = nil;

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [[Pushbots sharedInstance] clearBadgeCount];
        });

        pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK];
        [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
    }];
}

- (void) unregister:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command
{
    [self.commandDelegate runInBackground:^{
        CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = nil;

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [[Pushbots sharedInstance] unregister];
        });

        pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK];
        [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
    }];
}


- (void) setBadge:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command
{
    NSLog(@"Executing setBadge(count)");

    CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = nil;

    NSString* count = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];
    int badge = [count intValue];

    [[Pushbots sharedInstance] setBadge:badge];

    pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK];
    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge it's not possible to change from a banner notification to an alert notification outside the app programmatically. Not even if you were doing this natively.

The user has to go into Settings > Notifications > Your App > Select "Alerts" instead of "Banners".

There's no other way around it, sorry :(